# How do I use case expression then use an insert statement in the else part of the statement in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have below code but throws a syntax error in the else part.

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 ("Name") 
values 
((SELECT CASE 
           WHEN EXISTS(select "OccupationID" from "tbloccupations" where "Name" = '-') 
              THEN (select "OccupationID" from "tbloccupations" where "Name" = '-') 
           ELSE (INSERT INTO "tbloccupations" ("Name") VALUES ('-') RETURNING "OccupationID") 
           END)
);
```

This the actual query that is supposed to run thanks for your help:

```
ALTER TABLE tblcustomers DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
INSERT INTO public.tblcustomers
("CustomerID","Surname","OtherNames","Sex","DateOfBirth","OccupationID","Residence","PostalAddress","TownID",
 "NextOfKin","NextOfKinRelationship","NextOfKinContact","EmailAddress","DateRegistered","IDTypeID","IDNumber",
 "OutPatientNo","InPatientNo","Telephone1","Telephone2","PostalCode","Note","ReferenceNo","NationalityID",
 "RegisteredAtCompanyBranchID","RegisteredBySysUID","IsActive") 
 VALUES('-2','-','-','0','12/12/2012 12:00:00 AM',
        (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(select "OccupationID" from "tbloccupations" where "Name" = '-') 
         THEN(select "OccupationID" from "tbloccupations" where "Name" = '-') 
         ELSE(INSERT INTO "tbloccupations" ("Name") VALUES ('-') RETURNING "OccupationID") END),
        '-','-',
        (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(select "TownID" from "tbltowns" where "Name" = '-') THEN
         (select "TownID" from "tbltowns" where "Name" = '-') 
         ELSE(INSERT INTO "tbltowns" ("Name") VALUES ('-') RETURNING "TownID") END),
        '-','-','-','-','9/10/2014 12:00:00 AM','0','-','0','0','-','-','-','-','-','0','0','0','1') 
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;ALTER TABLE tblcustomers ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question which helps to explain the problem.

Comment: You have nested `INSERT` statements. That's bound to fail. Also, a select statement  must return exactly one value, so this is most likely why your `THEN (select "OccupationID" from "tbloccupations" where "Name" = '-')` is failing.

Comment: Is there a better way??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your logic correctly, you want to insert the `OccupationID` when the name is a `-`, otherwise you want to insert `-`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (Name)
SELECT CASE WHEN Name = '-' THEN OccupationID ELSE '-' END
FROM tbloccupations
RETURNING OccupationID;
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to use subqueries in the `VALUES` clause as you are currently doing it, but in any case your problem better fits an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Note: If the `OccupationID` column be numeric, then you'll have to cast it to text using something like `OccupationID::text`, in order to make the `CASE` expression work.

Comment: I want to select occupation Id else insert and return the id

Comment: it works well if the case part contains only select statement so am wondering why is failing when I use insert statement in that else part.

Comment: Please address the comment I left under your question above.